# mongodb upgrade from version 1.8 to 2.4

Tags: mongodb

Hi I need to upgrade mongodb standalone server from 1.4.5 to 2.4 and a replica set from 1.8.3 to 2.4. I have got docs to upgrade from 2.2 to 2.4. But I am not able to get docs upgrading mongodb from version 1.4 to 2.4 or from 1.8 t o2.4. In one of the documents I found that to upgrade from 2.0 to 2.4, its first needed to upgrade to 2.2 and then to 2.4. So do I need to do gradual upgrade?

Comment: As to whether you need to do a gradual upgrade depends on whether you are willing to take down the whole replia set for a short period or whether you wish to do the upgrade seamlessly by moving from one node to the next

Comment: I don't want to shut down the whole replica set. I just want to upgrade each of the members one by one.

Comment: Then you will need to upgrade from 1.4 to 1.8 first and then 1.8 to 2.0 and 2.0 to 2.4, that should be a safe method

Comment: @Sammaye, I don't understand, why do I need to do so. Can't I just upgrade to 2.4?

Comment: You could but I must be honest I cannot remember if there is some nasty change between the two, I know that members of 1.4 are not compatible with members of 2.4 I do know that much, if you was to upgrade to 1.8 I can sure that all members (of a replica set) of 1.8 would be compatible with 2.4